# flutter dart JsonSerializable with inherited class

Tags: flutter, inheritance, dart, jsonserializer

I have the following two classes where one is extending from the other like this :

```
@JsonSerializable(nullable: true)
class Response {
  final String responseCode;
  final String responseMessage;
  final String errorLog;
  Response({this.errorLog, this.responseCode, this.responseMessage});
  factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ResponseFromJson(json);
}
```

.........................................................

```
 @JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
class Verify extends Response {
  Data data;
  Verify({
    this.data,
  });
  factory Verify.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$VerifyFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$VerifyToJson(this);
}
```

and whenever I'm trying to read **response** class properties from Verify  class, it's always null.

so please how to achieve this?

Comment: [tag:datacontractjsonserializer] *is a .NET component that makes it possible to directly serialize .NET objects into JSON data*.  Since you are using flutter and dart and not c# or any other .Net language, I removed the tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

this one I have solved by passing the parameters to super in verify class  constructor like this

```
@JsonSerializable()
class VerifyResponse extends Response {
  Data data;

  VerifyResponse({
    this.data,
    String responseCode,
    String responseMessage,
  }) : super(responseCode: responseCode, responseMessage: responseMessage);

  factory VerifyResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$VerifyResponseFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$VerifyResponseToJson(this);
}
```

and for the response class it remains the same

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Response {
  final String responseCode;
  final String responseMessage;

  Response({this.responseCode, this.responseMessage});

  factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ResponseFromJson(json);
}
```

it's a bit annoying but it's what it's.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove 'final' keyword from Response Class

```
@JsonSerializable(nullable: true)
    class Response {
      String responseCode;
      String responseMessage;
      String errorLog;
      Response({this.errorLog, this.responseCode, this.responseMessage});
      factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
           _$ResponseFromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: Removing "final" keyword in base class members fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: why? what would be the point of removing final.

it only means that this value will be taken from the contracture

Comment: It does not make sense to remove `final` if the fields are intended to be immutable.

Answer (score 0):

It worked by adding `super();` explicitly to the child class's constructor.

```
@JsonSerializable()
class VerifyResponse extends Response {
  Data data;

  VerifyResponse({
    this.data,
    String responseCode,
    String responseMessage,
    //No need to list all parent class properties
    }) : super();

  factory VerifyResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$VerifyResponseFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$VerifyResponseToJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend the answer as there are a couple more gotchas.

You can't use the `super.responseCode` syntax in the constructor:

**Incorrect**

```
  VerifyResponse({
    this.data,
    super.responseCode,
    super.responseMessage,
  })
```

**Correct**

```
  VerifyResponse({
    this.data,
    String responseCode,
    String responseMessage,
  }) : super(responseCode: responseCode, responseMessage: responseMessage);
```

You also have to define the type in the constructor, otherwise they get passed to the super constructor as `dynamic`:

**Incorrect**

```
  VerifyResponse({
    required this.data,
    required responseCode,
    required responseMessage,
  }) : super(responseCode: responseCode, responseMessage: responseMessage);
```

**Correct**

```
  VerifyResponse({
    required this.data,
    required String responseCode,
    required String responseMessage,
  }) : super(responseCode: responseCode, responseMessage: responseMessage);
```